# ActionScript 3 and SSH

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, ssh

Is there a library for SSH in ActionScript 3? If not, I'd appreciate some ideas on how to have Flash integrate with SSH.

I have a Flash prototype programmed out, and my client wants to see some minimal integration with an SSH server. What is needed is basically:

- connect
- authenticate
- send a few basic commands

I can't just have these commands be sent out blindly, as I need Flash to be aware of the SSH feedback and let the user know if the authentication, commands, etc were successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that there is any SSH client implementation for AS3.  Do you really need it to be SSH or just some protected protocol?  Flash can pretty easily read https - so if you just need it to be encrypted you could use https to send/receive your data.

Otherwise you'd probably have to port the OpenSSH client to AS3 - not an easy task -- and the client site would still need to have a flash policy file to allow a flash client to open the SSH port (22?)

Comment: I'm working with a very specific setup of Cisco hardware, and have to use SSH. Some of their stuff uses a Telnet tunnel for SSH, so I'm going to see if that option is available. I've already got a AS-Telnet tunnel setup.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you're using Adobe AIR you have a pretty clean solution.

Using [Adobe AIR's NativeProcess](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html) feature, you can launch an SSH client from AS3 and communicate with it.
[putty.exe](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) is a great and simple ssh client but does not work from command-line on its own. fortunately, plink.exe which is kind of an add-on software that works with putty (downloadable on the same page), allows putty.exe to be launched and used from classic command-line (thus by NativeProcess).

This way, you just have to download putty.exe and plink.exe, put them in the bin folder of your application (so it works autonomously), and launch a NativeProcess from your AIR/AS3 program.

Simple and clean.

Hope that helps, even if the original thread is pretty old :)